# Comma issues in mustache conditional block elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, mustache, elasticsearch-template

I'm building a search template with mustache for elasticsearch with a bool query but I've got issues with my conditional block

I've code this part of the template :

```
\"must\":[
                        {{#query_string}}
                        {\"multi_match\":{
                            \"query\":\"{{query_string}}\",
                            \"fields\": [
                                \"cdm_cours_2_title.text^5\",
                                \"cdm_cours_4_resume.text\", 
                                \"cdm_cours_5_description.text\"
                            ]
                        }},{{/query_string}}
                        {{#title}}
                        {\"match\":{\"cdm_cours_2_title.text\":\"{{title}}\"}},
                        {{/title}}
                        {{#resume}}
                        {\"match\":{\"cdm_cours_4_resume.text\":\"{{resume}}\"}},
                        {{/resume}}
                        {{#description}}
                        {\"match\":{\"cdm_cours_5_description.text\":\"{{description}}\"}}
                        {{/description}}
                    ]
                    
                }},
```

But the issue is that I want to be able to set values for one, none or multiple parameters of this query and the comma are messing things up. I don't know how I can do it correctly.
In this configuration it doesn't work if you don't set the last field and I don't know how to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

A common way of solving this is to make your template support an array of queries and specify which one is the `last` one.

Here the template will loop through an array of `queries` and the comma will be added **if and only if** the query is NOT tagged as the last one in the array:

```
  {{#queries}}
    {{#query_string}}
      {\"multi_match\":{
         \"query\":\"{{value}}\",
         \"fields\": [
            \"cdm_cours_2_title.text^5\",
            \"cdm_cours_4_resume.text\", 
            \"cdm_cours_5_description.text\"
         ]
      }}
      {{^last}},{{/last}}
    {{/query_string}}
    {{#title}}
      {\"match\":{\"cdm_cours_2_title.text\":\"{{value}}\"}}
      {{^last}},{{/last}}
    {{/title}}
    {{#resume}}
      {\"match\":{\"cdm_cours_4_resume.text\":\"{{value}}\"}}
      {{^last}},{{/last}}
    {{/resume}}
    {{#description}}
      {\"match\":{\"cdm_cours_5_description.text\":\"{{value}}\"}}
      {{^last}},{{/last}}
    {{/description}}
  {{/queries}}
```

Then you need to invoke your query like this:

```
POST index/_search/template
{
  "id": "my-query",
  "params": {
    "queries": [
      {
        "query_string": {
          "value": "my-query-string"
        }
      },
      {
        "title": {
          "value": "my-title"
        }
      },
      {
        "resume": {
          "value": "my-resume"
        }
      },
      {
        "description": {
          "value": "my-description",
          "last": true                    <--- the last condition has last = true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can specify any number of conditions and in any order, but the last one MUST have `last: true` specified.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Can a match_all line in the end be a solution too ? I don't know if it's a "clean" way of doing it

Comment: it depends whether those queries are in a bool/should or not... if it's in a must or filter, you can add a match_all, but it's not really "clean"

Comment: You wrote "if and only if", but you mean "unless".

Comment: @Julian good point, I forgot "NOT" in my sentence, updated!